# Unable to access ingress k8s resources after using rewrite-target annotation

Tags: kubernetes, frontend, kubernetes-ingress

I have a K8s cluster, with two services - one service serving the front end static files and the other for backend. To differentiate between the two, I am using an ingress and a rest call to xyz.com/ is directed to the frontend service and rest calls to xyz.com/rest/abc are directed to the backend service (which is an api gateway and collection of services behind it). When creating an ingress, if i use the rewrite target annotation to rewrite xyz.com/rest/abc to xyz/com/abc, then i start getting errors when trying to access the front end service..
The errors that I have faced are

```
Did not parse stylesheet .... because non css mime types are not allowed in strict mode
Syntax error: Unexpected token < (while parsing bundle.js)
```

but if i am not using the rewrite annotation, then all files are transferred without any issue and the page is rendered as it should

annotation being used:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

using `nginx ingress controller`

Not sure why this is happening, could anyone help, any pointers, or any error that I am making.

Instead of using the path: `"/"` for the frontend service, i tried giving a more exact path `"/ui"` but it still gives the same issue.

New to K8s and ingress, so stuck here, and not sure what to do.

Ingress ->

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-ingress
  labels:
    name: sample-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /rest(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 8080
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /()
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port: 
              number: 3000
```

Comment: Please post your complete ingress definition. $2 is referencing a capture group from an path (the second). Do you have two capture groups?

Comment: @user2311578 my bad, added the complete definition

Answer (score 0):

For me it's still not clear what the desired behavior is. If you want to have

```
/rest/restpath -> backend-service/restpath
```

and

```
/uipath -> frontend-service/uipath
```

then your ingress could look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-ingress
  labels:
    name: sample-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /rest/(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 8080
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port: 
              number: 3000
```

Comment: Hey, so the desired behaviour is similar to what you have done, but when i try to do it and add the rewrite annotation, the front end breaks as in i start getting these errors  ::: Did not parse stylesheet .... because non css mime types are not allowed in strict mode
Syntax error: Unexpected token < (while parsing bundle.js)

Comment: Basically if i remove the rewrite annotation -- my js/html/css files are served and the page is rendered
But if i use the rewrite annotation to achieve the behavior that you have mentioned, the frontend files are not served properly

Comment: Can you examine with the browser's dev tools what the response of the call to bundle.js is? I mean its content and respose headers?